# move_uploaded_file() return false

Tags: php, image, file-upload

Please help me to solve the problem. i'm trying to to upload the image with extension jpg using `move_uploaded_file()` function. my image upload code is below:

my condition is always become false please help me to solve the issue.

```
$file_path = '3499738f724b2ae08a1871b6a0a7d175aaaaaaaaaa.jpg';
$fileURL = 'http://demo.deftbit.com/umeedtv/prog_image/';

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['vdoImg']['tmp_name'], $fileURL . $file_path)){
     echo 'Image Uploading Done.';
}else{
    echo 'Image Uploading fail try again later.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work, because move_uploaded_file('file tmp path','local root dir path') 2nd para. is wrong. So give root path in file name like

```
$file_path = '$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']'.'your folders/3499738f724b2ae08a1871b6a0a7d175aaaaaaaaaa.jpg';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide directory path not the url path you have provided url path in second parameter that is wrong.

To get current directory path you can use `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your file path is in the default directory where it is searching for. Try appending the root path to it and see.